# Python Selenium Focusing a Certain Browser Instance

Tags: python, selenium

I built a tkinter app with n buttons, which starts n different selenium browsers. For every browser, I want to create another button, that focuses that specific browser, meaning that it will pop up in front of any other browser or the tkinter app itself, but I didn't find any function that puts a browser in front. How can I do this? Is it possible in python?

Comment: Try these examples. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200168/how-to-bring-selenium-browser-to-the-front

Comment: Thanks. Some of the answers worked. The idea is that I first need to minimize the browser and then to maximize it (or just a set a size that I want) and it will pop up in foreground.