# How to bring browser to front and maximize using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on automating a section of data entry using a mixture of Selenium and Pyautogui.

I have the manual automated part down using the module Pyautogui but I need to bring the browser to the front so the mouse and keyboard can interact with the browser.

All the solutions I've tried maximizes the window but it stays in the background.

Comment: Try the answers to [How to bring the Selenium browser to front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200168/how-to-bring-selenium-browser-to-the-front)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle)
```

Answer (score 0):

To bring the browser to frontground and maximize using *Selenium* and *Python* you can use the following set of lines:

```
driver.execute_script("window.focus();")
driver.maximize_window()
```